# How do I reduce a score from inside a function

Tags: python, reduce

Trying to get my first program to work. I am trying to subtract the score depending on the users input. But my score will not change the way it is now. Could you help me understand what is going wrong?

Below you can see the code I am trying to run:

```
    score = 75
    def round_1(score):
        shots_1 = input("What did you score: ")
        if shots_1 == 1:
            return score - 1
        elif shots_1 == 2:
            return score - 2
        elif shots_1 == 3:
            return score - 3
        else:
            return score
```

Comment: `int(input("What did you score: "))`. By default `input()` returns a string, you need to convert it to an int.

Comment: `input()` returns a string value, but you're checking for integer values.  None of your `if` statements are true, and so the `else` is always executed.

Comment: You have to actually *do something* with the return value for a `return` statement to be meaningful.  Show us the code where you call this function.

Comment: wrap input() with int() or use `if shots_1 == '1'` and so on

Comment: @RobinBorg don't forget to accept answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Command line `input` always comes in `string` format. You have to covert to desire format based on input from user.

```
def round_1(score):
    shots_1 = int(input("What did you score: "))
    print(shots_1)
    if shots_1 == 1:
        return score - 1
    elif shots_1 == 2:
        return score - 2
    elif shots_1 == 3:
        return score - 3
    else:
        return score
        

print(round_1(75))
```

You can read here more about typecasting. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/taking-input-from-console-in-python/

Answer (score 2):

Your problem was with datatypes. You have to convert shots_1 to int. or type it out as shots_1 == '1':

Comment: The intent of the function is to return the score minus a number, so using `'1'` is not enough.  It will have to be converted to integer.

Comment: well in this function hes not using shots_1 for anything other than conditioning the if statement. I would agree if it was score - shots_1

Comment: Ahh, so it is.  My mistake.

Answer (score 1):

`input`returns a string, so all of these `if`s will be false:

```
    if shots_1 == 1:
        return score - 1
    elif shots_1 == 2:
        return score - 2
    elif shots_1 == 3:
        return score - 3
```

You could do this instead:

```
    if shots_1 == '1':
        return score - 1
    elif shots_1 == '2':
        return score - 2
    elif shots_1 == '3':
        return score - 3
```

Answer (score 1):

when you ask for input it automatically takes the input as a string so you should convert the options to strings also since your code is inside a def function you need to run it first:

```
score = 75
def round_1(score):
    shots_1 = input("What did you score: ")
    if shots_1 == '1':
        print(score-1)
    elif shots_1 == '2':
        print(score-2)
    elif shots_1 =='3':
        print(score-3)
    else:
        print(score)
round_1(75)
```